# PHP floor function

Tags: php, floating-point

Does anyone know why `floor(61681) = 61681`, but `floor(616.81*100) = 61680` ?

I have tried many others values like

```
floor(716.81*100) = 71681
floor(816.81*100) = 81681
floor(916.81*100) = 91681
floor(616.83*100) = 61683
```

Anyone know why this happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the nature of binary floating-point numbers, internal rounding inaccuracies will occur. There is no way to represent `616.81` as a binary floating-point number exactly - its closest approximation is in fact slightly less than `616.81`. `61681` can be represented exactly, however.

When the representation of `616.81` is multiplied by `100`, the result is a tiny bit less than `61681`, and thus calling `floor` on it will return `61680`.

http://codepad.org/H0wh2itg

If you want absolute precision, you can use PHP's BC math functions, which can be as precise as you need at the cost of performance. For example:

```
var_dump(floor(bcmul(616.18, 100, 12)));
```

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. There are internal rounding inaccuracies that are inherent to the nature of binary floating-point numbers. This means that it is impossible to represent some numbers, such as `616.81`, exactly. In addition, as codepad.org runs the code on a real PHP interpreter, I have used it as a proof. Please rescind your downvote, as my answer is correct.

Comment: Because the routines that print floating-point numbers do not print the exact internal representation, but rather one that is rounded back to show what you may expect. I'd suggest that you read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: From http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/ - "In other cases like 0.1 + 0.3, the result actually isn’t really 0.4, but close enough that 0.4 is the shortest number that is closer to the result than to any other floating-point number. Many languages then display that number instead of converting the actual result back to the closest decimal fraction."

Comment: Not a problem; I'm happy to help. This is quite a common question among developers, actually, and it exposes one of the possible pitfalls of floating-point numbers that every developer should be aware of. If you feel that this answer is appropriate, you may choose to accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: You could add to your answer that the solution is to use the BC Math functions: `var_dump(floor(bcmul(616.18, 100, 12)));`, where 12 is the precision (number of digits after the dot).